# Raspberry pi model 3 b overheating

Tags: pi-3

I have shorted 5v and Gnd pins accidentally. Thereafter pi stopped booting.

So I re-installed rasbian image on SD card and it is booting now. But there is a problem: Temperature reported by raspberry pi overshoots up to 90 Celsius and heat sink doesn't help.

Anybody know how to find out why its overheating though I am not overclocking it?

Comment: It is on its way to the grave.

Comment: There is nothing I can do about it ? Pi turns off itself after 90 Celsius.

Comment: No, it is dead (or dying).

Comment: Not necessarily, what is the real CPU temperature? If you don't have a temperature probe, use your finger. If it's tolerable heat, you're at 50°, if it's 80° or higher you can't keep your finger pressed for more than a second. If it is unbroken, you can adjust the temp at which to throttle cpu, in config.txt

Comment: As I mentioned the temperature reaches 90 degree Celsius. After sometime RPI shutdown itself (this might due to throttling).

Answer (score 1):

You've killed your Pi. Time to buy another one.